# Document_root from another server

Tags: php

So I have code like these on my PHP, let say my PHP on server A

```
$mdb_file = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/sapfiles/web_supp/PEB_MDB/dbPEB.mdb");
if (!file_exists($mdb_file)){
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
```

But my problem is to get `$mdb_file` I needed a link to another server B, cause my file mdb on server B. So how to connect with using `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` from server B to server A?? And how to send it back from Server A to Server B any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] to load a file from another server. $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] is only for getting the current web host root directory. You could load the file via ftp from server B if it is running as an ftp host. Checkout the docs for ftp get : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: To bad,that server not ftp but file sharing :/

Comment: Is the file you want to load from that host static?

Comment: It is. Let said  both server not from my local computer, but both is host static .

Comment: Can you download the file from serverB and upload it to serverA? If so you could put it outside the web root, and with proper permissions access it using your php.

Comment: Well i can, but these database is always up to date, so i cant always copy databse everytime. Thats why i need more like document root or something to connect to that server.